# Update multiple records to equal other records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a large database with one-to-many relationships.  It's for computer systems at many different sites.  For each computer system there are different e-mail address that need to be set for automated messages, and these are stored in the DB.  For many of these computers, I need to make 2 or more of the records the same.  I want to write a query (in SQL Server 2005), that will allow me to update/copy all of the records at once.

For instance:

```
dbo.email table; 
system 1 emaila = x; 
system 1 emailb = y; 
system 2 emaila = z; 
system 2 emailb = aa;
```

I need system 1 emailb = system 1 emaila, and I need system 2 emailb = system 2 emailb.

Is this possible using one query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
with toupdate as (
      select et.*,
             min(email) over (partition by system) as an_email
      from emailtable et
     )
update toupdate
    set email = an_email;
```

Comment: @AndriyM . . . That seems like a good idea.  The OP would just need to be careful about NULL values.

Comment: I will test and get back with you.